# Node.js / NPM: Error Handling

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a running karma test with webpack, jasmine and angular2. When I upgrade a package to the newest version my test fails with

```
 code ELIFECYLCE
 Exit status 32212236505
```

The npm-debug.log is also not helpful.

```
14 verbose stack Error: squidex@1.0.0 test: `karma start --log-level debug`
14 verbose stack Exit status 3221226505
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mail2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mail2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

I would like to find out what is going on to give the package author some more information.

How can I get detailed loggings or a better error message? Why can I not get a stacktrace?

Comment: Did you update all dependences and global packages? Are you using a supported version of node and npm?

Comment: Yes, the latest npm version and a updated node version some weeks ago. I only changed this single package.